# Disable ROUND function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, rounding

As an extention to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706055/how-to-do-a-special-type-of-rounding-in-excel-vba), I'm trying to engineer some controls to prevent users in my lab from using Excel's `ROUND` function (operating procedures require us to use the round-to-even/banker's rounding method).

I found it rather simple to write the function to get the correct rounding

```
Function RoundEven(num, precision)
  RoundEven = Round(num, precision)
End Function
```

What I would like to do in addition to this is disable the `ROUND` function altogether.  I tried adding

```
Function Round()
  Round = "Bad Rounding Technique"
End Function
```

But this overwrote the rounding method in `RoundEven`, and so any rounding I attempt ends up returning the "Bad Rounding Technique" message.

What's the proper way to assign `Round` a new local value while still having `RoundEven` pull VBA's default rounding method.

Comment: I realize this is probably impractical, but in many ways you'd be better off avoiding Excel altogether.

Comment: Agreed!  This is a stop gap measure until the database is complete.  We'll be phasing out these worksheets over the next year.  But compliance isn't so patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can write your own `ROUND` function and have it replace the Excel's. I just tried it in 2010. Both mine and Excel's show up in intellisense, but regardless of the one I pick, it evaluates as built-in `ROUND`.

You could use a change event to change any instance of `ROUND` to `ROUNDEVEN'

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Target.Cells
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            rCell.Formula = Replace$(rCell.Formula, "ROUND(", "ROUNDEVEN(")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

This is in the sheet's module if you only care about one sheet. You'd need the ThisWorkbook module or a custom class module with an Application variable declare WithEvents depending on how broad a scope you need.

This will definitely work for simple stuff, but I'm quite sure there are circumstances that will break it.

Another thing you could do is validate the formulas before some critical moment. Instead of real-time fixing the problem, just check every cell in the worksheet prior to it being submitted (or whatever the critical event is). You could use the ThisWorkbook BeforeSave event to prevent the user from saving, for instance, if there are any formulas with `ROUND(` in them.

Comment: You're right, Excel won't let me overwrite its `ROUND` function. Which makes sense, but also makes me sad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, but try using: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round` to get the original function. (And hope what you do doesn't override it).

---

Why don't you simply override the `Round` function and forget about RoundEven?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round` would invoke Excel's rounding method, which would effectively redefine VBA's round to the Excel round.  This understanding is actually why I haven't tried it, is my understanding incorrect?  Also, I don't want to override `Round` for validation purposes.  If I overwrite `Round`, it's a lot harder to tell if the correct routine is in place.  Disabling `Round` and implementing `RoundEven` makes it a lot easier to determine if the spreadsheets are using the correct rounding algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
dim callingFunctionName as string ' we need a global variable to let Round know who is calling it

Function RoundEven(num, precision)
  callingFunctionName  = "RoundEven"
  RoundEven = Round(num, precision)
End Function

   '' Disable Round function from callers other than RoundEven (In fact you can have a safelist of functions that can call this function now)
Function Round()
  if callingFunctionName   = "RoundEven" then 
    '' allow Round here
  else
     Round = "Bad Rounding Technique"
  end if
End Function
```

Comment: Working on this now.  As is, it isn't working, but I might be able to work it out.